# Inclusion relations between equationally defined classes of finite semigroups

Tags: model-theory, formal-languages, semigroups, universal-algebra, finite-semigroups

Let $S, T$ be two semigroups. In the following all semigroups are supposed to be finite. We write $S \prec T$ if there exists a surjective semigroup morphism from a subsemigroup of $T$ onto $S$. A class of finite semigroups $\mathcal V$ is defined by a set of equations if exactly the semigroup in $\mathcal V$ fulfill those equations, similar for a class of finite monoids. Let $\mathcal W$ be a class of monoid, we denote by $\mathcal W_S$ the class of semigroups
$$
 \mathcal W_S = \{ S \mbox{ is a semigroup} \mid  S \prec M, M \in \mathcal W \}
$$
where the monoid $M$ is considered as a semigroup. Let $R_n$ denote the class of monoid defined by
$$
 (xy)^n x = (xy)^n.
$$
Then the class of semigroup $(R_n)_S$ is defined by the equations
$$
 x^{n+1} = x^n, \quad
 (xy)^n x = (xy)^n.
$$
Denote by $V_n$ the class of semigroups defined by the single equation
$$
 (xy)^n  x = (xy)^n.
$$
Show that
$$
 (R_n)_S \subseteq V_n \subseteq (R_{n+1})_S.
$$
Hint: Utilize the free semigroup over two generators and its subsemigroup of sequenezes of length at least $k$ for suitable $k$.

This is exercise V.3.2 from [Samuel Eilenberg, Automata, Machines and Languages, Volume B](https://books.google.de/books?id=YkuXEJ34xF0C&pg=PA109&hl=de&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false).

The inclusion $(R_n)_S \subseteq V_n$ is obvious, for properness we can look at the cyclic semigroup $S = \{x,x^2, \ldots, x^{n+1}\}$ with $x^{n+2} = x^{n+1}$. But for the other inclusion I have no idea? I see that if we set $y = x$ we get $V_n \subseteq (R_{2n})_S$, but that is not enough.

Comment: Call your example $S_{n+1}$. Then $S_{2n}$, where $x^{2n+1}=x^{2n}$, seems to be in $V_n$, but it does not satisfy $x^{n+2}=x^{n+1}$ which indeed seems to be implied by being in $(R_{n+1}) _S$.

Comment: Yes, so the exercise is wrong? I also could not make much sense out of the hint given...

Comment: Based on our current understanding, I can imagine it's only a *typo*, meaning $(R_{2n})_S$ on the right hand side. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed a typo. The second inclusion fails for $n = 2$. Take the semigroup $\{a, a^2, a^3, a^4\}$ with $a^4 = a^5$. Then it satisfies the equation $(xy)^2x = (xy)^2$ but it does not satisfy the equation $x^4 = x^3$.